# React-router-bootstrap: LinkContainer redirects url but doesn't rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-router-bootstrap

I have a LinkContainer, that when clicked on, replaces the url of the webpage, but doesn't do anything beyond that. Nothing gets rerendered, the page just stays the same.

Eg;

```
<LinkContainer to={`/item/4`}><Button>Redirect</Button></LinkContainer>
```

If I'm on localhost:3000/item/1, it renders item 1 just fine. If I click that button, I'm on localhost:3000/item/4, but the page is still on item 1. It's not until I refresh does the page get updated to item 4.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide some additional information about how the routes are configured and the component you are trying to re-render.